# How can I return Response from method that call web service in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, web-services, appcelerator-studio

I'm building a Service Android with appcelerator studio.

In this service a call a web service that return a json.

So this is the code to call ws:

```
funtcion start(){
    var obj = getDocument("CFDECTEST02",NULL);
    Titanium.API.info("DOCUMENT "+ obj);
}

function getDocument(fiscalCode, date){
    //se il servizio può partire, procedo con il chiamare il ws
    // create request
    var obj;
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    //set timeout
    xhr.setTimeout(10000);
    //Here you set the webservice address and method
    xhr.open('POST', "http://Document/");
    //set enconding
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    var myObject = {
         cf :fiscalCode,
         date_last_synchronization :date 
    };
    //send request with parameters
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myObject));
    // function to deal with errors
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        Ti.API.info("SERVIZIO IN ERRORE");
        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
        disattivaSemaforo();
    };

    // function to deal with response
   xhr.onload = function() {
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
        return obj;
    };

}
```

Now I want that if the WS return the correct response I return the response to the method start.

Then if when I try to call web service, it is all ok, the method

```
xhr.onload = function() {
```

is execute, and I can do return obj to start() method.

It is possibile to do this?

Comment: If you need an asynchronous return value, use promises or callbacks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: How can I use callbacks?